# Debian 9 on acer aspire 7 doesn't detect wifi ( intel AC 9560 )

Tags: debian, wifi, iwlwifi

I installed Debian 9 on my acer aspire 7 (A715-72G-75XG) laptop. However the network-manager does not detect wi-fi. Those are the outputs of a few commands:

```
$iwlist wlan0 scan
 wlan0     Interface doesn't support scanning.


lspci -knn | grep -i net
 00:14.3 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Device        
[8086:a370] (rev 10)
 06:00.1 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.                                          
 RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller 
 [10ec:8168]                                      (rev 12)
      Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express 
Gigabit Ethernet Controller [1025:125e]
```

I have no idea what to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install the `linux-image` and the [`firmware-iwlwifi`](https://packages.debian.org/stretch-backports/firmware-iwlwifi) (non-free) from [backports](https://wiki.debian.org/Backports).

add the following line to your `/etc/apt/sources.list`:

```
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-backports main contrib non-free
```

Then :

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt -t stretch-backports linux-image-4.19.0-0.bpo.5-amd64 firmware-iwlwifi
sudo reboot
```

[Intel Dual Band Wireless-AC 9560](https://wikidevi.com/wiki/Intel_Dual_Band_Wireless-AC_9560_(9560NGW))

[Intel® Wireless-AC 9560](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000005511/network-and-i-o/wireless-networking.html) : A kernel version 4.14+ is required.

[PCI-IDS  Device 8086:a370](http://pci-ids.ucw.cz/read/PC/8086/a370) : Name: Wireless-AC 9560 [Jefferson Peak]

Comment: I'm assuming you meant `sudo apt -t stretch-backports install linux-image-amd64 firmware-iwlwifi` ? In that case I get `The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 linux-image-amd64 : Depends: linux-image-4.19.0-0.bpo.5-amd64 but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
`
I was able to install firmware-iwlwifi though, but it still doesn't detect wifi..

Comment: @RUBENGONÇALOMOROUÇO `sudo apt -t stretch-backports install linux-image-4.19.0-0.bpo.5-amd64` , the kernel should be upgraded.

Comment: it worked.. I'd like however to understand why was it necessary to install that other linux image. And also since it's a "backport" is it safe to use? Does it still receive security updates?

Comment: @RUBENGONÇALOMOROUÇO A kernel version 4.14+ is required. As mentioned in the intel website (last link in my answer).

Comment: oh I see. Just one more thing, how/where did you see what wireless my computer uses?

Comment: @RUBENGONÇALOMOROUÇO from the output of `lspci` , the `[8086:a370]` is the ID of the Intel Dual Band Wireless-AC 9560.